# How to pass Rspec test has_many? [Shoulda-matchers]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, dtd, shoulda

I´m trying rails to develop a rest api. I´m using rspec and shoulda-matchers. The problem is that one of my test always fails.

How can I correct my code, so the test passes (GREEN).

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cards
end
```

card.rb

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

user_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
    before { @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) } 

    subject{ @user }

    # Columns
    it { should respond_to :name }

    # Associations
    it { should have_many :cards }
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'rails-api'

gem 'spring', :group => :development


gem 'sqlite3'


group :development, :test do
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Terminal

```
➜  my_api  rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
.F

Failures:

  1) User should have many :cards
     Failure/Error: it { should have_many :cards }
       expected #<User:0x007f897ce0c0d8> to respond to `has_many?`
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.04623 seconds (files took 2.45 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:12 # User should have many :cards
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup the association between the models properly in your `user` and `card` factories.

```
factory :card do
  # ...
  association :user
end
```

Then, it should work.

See [this](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations) to know more about associations in factory-girl.

If the above doesn't fix your problem, try doing this way:

```
# spec/factories/user.rb

Factory.define :user, :class => User do |u|
    u.cards { |c| [c.association(:card)] }
end
```